# Question about bifunctors/bimodules

Tags: category-theory

I'm wondering how a functor $C \to D$ induces a bifunctor $C \times C^{op} \to D$ (it's an "example").

Am I downright stupid not seeing this?

Second problem I have:

For categories $C$ and $D$:

A topological leftmodule is a topological functor $C \to Top$

A topological rightmodule is a topological functor $D^{op} \to Top$

A topological bimodule is a topological bifunctor $C\times D^{op} \to Top$

Now a morphism $_CX \to _CY$ of leftmodules is a natural transformation of functors.

If we even have bimodules $_CX_A$ and $_CY_B$ , then we have a bimodule $_AHom_C(X,Y)_B$ .

Now I hit on this:

For $_AX_B$ a bimodule $X \cong Hom_A(A,X)$ naturally isomorphic as  $A$-$B$-bimodules.

Now I am wondering what bimodule is the $A$ supposed to be, all we know $A$ is a category.

Comment: Who claimed that it did? Are you sure the claim isn't that it induces a bifunctor $C \times D^{op} \to \text{Set}$?

Comment: "A (continous) functor $C \to D$ induces a $C-C$-bimodule structure on $D$" Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @x x: yes. The claim is that $D$ can be used to construct a bifunctor $C \times C^{op} \to \text{Set}$.

Comment: Ok I guess it's ment to be Hom(-,F(-)) then. Do you have a clue at my other question?

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now. :)

Comment: $A$ is an $(A, A)$-bimodule. The bimodule structure is given by $\text{Hom}(-, -)$.